# Convert string from ISO-2022-JP to UTF-8 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding

I have a `Buffer` with ISO-2020-JP encoded text which I need to convert to UTF-8. I have found number of libraries on the NPM, like:

- [encoding-japanese](https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding-japanese)
- [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite)

But I don't know and can't find anywhere, which exactly encoding in them corresponds to ISO-2020-JP. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [encoding.js](https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js).

```js
const Encoding = require('encoding-japanese');


const buffer = [27, 36, 66, 36, 51, 36, 115, 36, 75, 36, 65, 36, 79, 27, 40, 74]; // こんにちは in ISO-2022-JP

// if you want to convert an ISO-2022-JP byte array to a UTF-8 byte array:
const utf8Array = Encoding.convert(buffer, {
  to: 'UTF8',
  from: 'JIS'
});
console.log(utf8Array);

// if you want to convert ISO-2022-JP byte array to JavaScript string:
const unicodeArray = Encoding.convert(buffer, {
  to: 'UNICODE',
  from: 'JIS'
});
console.log(Encoding.codeToString(unicodeArray));
```